# Start a ProgressDialog when a user submits log in details

Tags: android, progressdialog

My android application has a login feature and it is accessing the users information from my online server. It can also detect a registered user whether he/she has activated his/her account through email message confirmation.

But my problem is, my application almost closes when it's retrieving users details from the database.. I have watched some videos regarding ProgressDialog and I don't know if it can be inserted in my program properly, please help me.

Here's my code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.firstscreen);

    initialise();

    bGotoRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {    
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });        
}

private void initialise()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginSubmit);
    tvEmailError = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.loginEmailError);
    tvPasswordError = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.loginPasswordError);
    bGotoRegister = (Button) findViewById (R.id.goToRegister);

    bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) 
{
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httppost = new HttpPost("http://mysite.com/login.php");
    stringEmail = etEmail.getText().toString();
    stringPassword = etPassword.getText().toString();

    try 
    {
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringEmail", stringEmail));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringPassword", stringPassword));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()== 200)
        {
            entity = response.getEntity();
            if(entity != null)
            {   
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));

                String errorEmail = jsonResponse.getString("errorEmail");
                if (errorEmail != "")
                {
                    tvEmailError.setText(errorEmail);
                }else{}

                String errorPassword = jsonResponse.getString("errorPassword");
                if (errorPassword != "")
                {
                    tvPasswordError.setText(errorPassword);
                }else{}

                String inactiveAccount = jsonResponse.getString("inactiveAccount");
                if (inactiveAccount.length() != 0)
                {                       
                    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(FirstScreen.this).create();
                    alert.setCancelable(false);
                    alert.setMessage("Your account is currently inactive and unusable." + "\nDo you want to send an account activation message to your email now?");
                    alert.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {   
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                        {
                            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            httppost = new HttpPost("http://mysite.com/activate2.php");
                            stringEmail = etEmail.getText().toString();
                            stringPassword = etPassword.getText().toString();

                            try
                            {
                                nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringEmail", stringEmail));
                                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringPassword", stringPassword));

                                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                                if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()== 200)
                                {
                                    entity = response.getEntity();
                                    if(entity != null)
                                    {
                                        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));

                                        String successActivation = jsonResponse.getString("successActivation");
                                        if (successActivation.length() != 0)
                                        {
                                            //Progress Dialog here.
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "We successfully sent an activation message to your email account. Try to log in again after activating your account.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, we are unable to reach your email account.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }   
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection to the server is lost. Please check your internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    alert.setButton2("Not now", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {   
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                        {
                            AlertDialog alert2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(FirstScreen.this).create();
                            alert2.setCancelable(false);
                            alert2.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");
                            alert2.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {   
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                                {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });
                            alert2.setButton2("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                            {   
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                                {
                                    //Do nothing
                                }
                            });
                            alert2.show();
                        }
                    });
                    alert.show();
                }else{}

                if ((errorEmail.length()==0) && (errorPassword.length()==0)&& (inactiveAccount.length()==0))
                {                       
                    String dbEmail = jsonResponse.getString("dbEmail");
                    String dbPassword = jsonResponse.getString("dbPassword");
                    //---Store dbEmail and dbPassword to SharedPreferences---//
                    //-------------------------------------------------------//
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Construction.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }

            }//if (entity!=null)..      
        }//if response()...
    }//try..
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection to the server is lost. Please check your internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   
}//END onClick()
```

Comment: Have you tried AsyncTask? Because that's what you're searching for ;)

Comment: Dont post the entire code.Only post some parts which is needed.If u post more code means then the readers are irritated they dont respond it.B4 post the entire code (large number of codes) think which is important only that part u post.Because if the code is very large means then it is very hard to understand ur needs,ur problem,etc.If code is too big means no one try to read it.But if the code is simple,short means then all of them read it and try to give their ideas.

Comment: @SIVAKUMAR.J - Excuse me, sir. I did not post the entire code of my program. In the first place, everything that I have posted is needed for the readers to understand how 'long' my program is taking to respond, and they gave me some idea to solve it. Thanks, but I'm going to read the links and answers that they have given me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are establishing a HTTP Connection on Main thread which is a bad way of programming in Android.

The Web Connection is kind of a blocking call that mean your Main thread will be struck on onClick until there is a response received from the server in either success or failure.

As the Main Thread is blocked in network connection your App becomes unresponsive to the other events such as Touch / tap or any kind of life cycle events and will not be able to update the UI as well. Which is why your application will crash / no update is displayed in the progress Dialog.

I recommend you to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for any network related tasks so that your Main thread is not blocked.

Comment: Thanks for the info sir. I transferred my web connection methods in an Async class, but I am still confused. My emulator only shows the ProgressDialog, and I don't think it really shows the progress of what actually happens in my app. Please help me..

Comment: Yes, that's expected.. now in your AsyncTask post the progress to the main thread so that the progress bar is updated... check any example of AsyncTask on web and you will know how to post the progress such that it is updated on the UI.

Comment: Sir, I still have this problem. I tried to use the horizontal progress dialog, and it proved me that it's not showing the progress of what actually happens in my app, it only displays the progress dialog and immediately disappears after a second without getting even 1 % progress. Please help me.

Comment: Did you override the method "onProgressUpdate()" this will be called on UI thread such that it can update the Progress Bar. Also dont forget to call "publishProgress()" from your "doInBackground()" method. [Check this for more info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Almost all of examples that I've seen that uses onProgressUpdate() method has some numerical values to pass in to set the progress of the ProgressDialog. But how will I do it if I don't have any? I will only be using this for Log in & Sign up activities. Is it possible to determine the real progress of this one and set it to my onProgressUpdate() method?

Comment: Then do not use a Horizontal Progress bar what you need is a Indefinite Progress Bar, for the same Bar set the property indefinite as true.

Comment: Sorry, sir. But I still can not completely get it. Is an indefinite Progress Bar that you're talking about is the one that spins? And what's indefinite property? Do I still need to pass in some numerical values to set a ProgressUpdate?

Comment: Yes, The Progress bar that spins indefinitely and no need to pass any numerical values to update the progress... [check this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing Network operations Login and retrieving details in Event thread, instead you should do this in another thread than Event thread, or in AsyncTask.

By Progress Dialog, you can show that there is some processing being in progress.

I am writing a sample code to how to use progress dialog, thread, and handler in your program:

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(v.getContext(), "Login",  "Logging In...." );
    Thread thread= new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
             httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httppost = new HttpPost("http://mysite.com/login.php");
    stringEmail = etEmail.getText().toString();
    stringPassword = etPassword.getText().toString();

    try 
    {
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringEmail", stringEmail));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringPassword", stringPassword));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()== 200)
        {
            entity = response.getEntity();
            if(entity != null)
            {   
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));

                String errorEmail = jsonResponse.getString("errorEmail");
                if (errorEmail != "")
                {
                    tvEmailError.setText(errorEmail);
                }else{}

                String errorPassword = jsonResponse.getString("errorPassword");
                if (errorPassword != "")
                {
                    Message msg= errHandler.obtainMessage();
                    msg.obj=errorPassword;
                    errHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                }else{}

                //


            }//if (entity!=null)..      
        }//if response()...
    }//try..
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection to the server is lost. Please check your internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   
        }
    }

Handler errHandler=new Handler()
{
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
          progressDialog.dismiss();
          String strErr=(String)msg.obj;
          tvEmailError.setText(strErr);
    }
};
```